# Dictionary field in parse.com

Tags: swift, dictionary, parse-platform

How can I create a field in `parse.com` that will contain a dictionary by using swift and parse web app?

I would like to create something like:

```
field1-String field2-String field3-Dictionary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the Dictionary in code, and at runtime you can push it to parse, and now (if you want) you can delete the code from your app.

Comment: Will i be able to create a database in parse.com like the following. How should I do it? fields:   brand |model |attributes
          ----------------------------
record 1) apple |iPhone|6s space grey sprint
record 2) audi  | a6   |quattro coupe

Comment: I'm not sure about dictionaries with 3 keys, the simplest way is (at least how i would do it :P) to make a class for it, inherited from NSObject, and then push it to parse. Alternately, you can make in the parse Class 3 columns for those keys.

Comment: if I use create a Dictionary in swift I am able to push that to parse as an Object field as field 3. How do I query that object field matching a keyword. for example : I wanted to list only iPhones that are silver in color.